# Do the verb "muse" and the noun "Muse" have a common etymology?

Tags: etymology

I was wondering about that: the *New Oxford American Dictionary* says *to muse* comes from the French *muser*, which comes from the Latin *musum*. The *Muse* comes form the Latin *musa*, which comes from the Greek *mousa*. Those sound close, but my Latin is too weak (and my Greek inexistent) to tell if they were related back in the antique days.

Comment: On a related note, I've established that *museum* comes from the same root as *Muse*: “via Latin from Greek *mouseion* (seat of the Muses), based on *mousa* (Muse).”

Comment: today's "who knew?" question, good one.  And here's everyone's favorite noun-Muse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWeJ9p42ufg  (now **thirty-five years** ago!) Obviously, Jeff Lynne's sound is still 50 years ahead of anything today, and what about those glow graphics and effects as the girls turn real!  Historic video!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Etymonline says [this about that](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=muse&searchmode=none):

> **muse** "to be absorbed in thought," mid-14c., from O.Fr. muser (12c.) "to ponder, loiter, waste time," lit. "to stand with one's nose in the air" (or, possibly, "to sniff about" like a dog who has lost the scent), from muse "muzzle," from Gallo-Romance *musa "snout," of unknown origin. Probably influenced in sense by muse (n.). Related: Mused; musing.

Comment: Wow! Without this I'd certainly have succumbed to folk etymology. It gets hard when analogy and folk etymology actually change the words themselves. +1

Comment: I am also surprised.

Comment: This issue seems fascinating, but I still totally don't understand which is which!

Answer (score 1):

[Middle English, from Old French, from Latin Mūsa, from Greek Mousa; see men-1 in the Appendix of Indo-European roots.]

Word History: Ever since Chaucer first mentions the Muses in a work from around 1390, English poets have invoked these goddesses like so many other versifiers since the days of Homer, who begins both The Iliad and The Odyssey with an invocation of his Muse. The word Muse comes from Latin Mūsa, which in turn is from Greek Mousa. In Greek dialects, this word is found in the variant forms mōsa and moisa, and together these indicate that the Greek word comes from an original *montwa. As to the further origins of this form, a clue is provided by the name of Mnemosyne, the goddess of memory and mother of the Muses. Her name is simply the Greek noun mnēmosunē, "memory"—the faculty of memory was indeed the mother of invention for the ancient Greek professional poets and bards whose job it was to compose new poems in traditional styles on festive occasions, to recite the verses of Homer, and to improvise material whenever they had a memory lapse. Greek mnēmosunē is derived from the root *mnā-, an extended form of the Greek and Indo-European root *men-, "to think." This is the root from which English also gets the words amnesia (from Greek), mental (from Latin), and mind (from Germanic). The reconstructed form *montwa, the ancestor of Greek Mousa, also comes from this root and probably originally referred to "mental power" that enables poets to craft verses—the Muses were the Greek poets' divinized conceptions of the faculties that help them to create and recite poetry.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition copyright ©2019 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be thought unlikely.

The etymology of the verb *muse* seems to be too obscure to trace it back clearly to a Latin etymology. As you mentioned, the English verb certainly seems to come from the French verb *muser.* The ending *-er* is just a termination for the infinitive of verbs in the 1st group (the largest conjugational class for French verbs).

The OED and the French [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/muser) (© 2012 - CNRTL) say that French *muser* is probably derived from an unattested Old French noun **mus* that meant something like "face"; the TLFi indicates that **mus* would also have been the base of the attested French word *museau.* The [TLFi entry for *museau*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/museau) (which originally had the form *musel,* with a diminutive suffix *-el*) indicates that it is akin to Italian *muso,* and says that both come from a Latin word *musus, -us* of obscure origin.

French *musel* is the source of English *muzzle*; the OED entry for that word also mentions Old French **mus* and says that "Postclassical Latin *musus* or *musum* is of uncertain origin".

The English and French noun *muse,* from Latin *Musa,* from Greek *Μοῦσα,* is not described by either of these sources as being related to the verb *muse(r),* from Old French **mus,* from Latin *musus/musum.*